# Envio de link seguro por e-mail, que permite o usuario acessar uma Action Edit na controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Eu preciso enviar por e-mail um link seguro para que o usuário ao clicar, possa acessar uma action Edit na controller.
Por Exemplo:

Envio do link: *localhost:64148/Movies/Edit?id=4*

Porém não posso enviar o link desta forma, pois quando o usuário acessá-lo, não será permitido devido o uso do `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`

Como faço para enviar um link seguro neste caso? Como lido com o token?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, em primeiro lugar realmente não seria muito seguro enviar o link desta forma, eu aconcelharia criar uma nova action, cujo o parametro seria um token criptografado onde, dentro deste token você enviaria algumas informações como uma chave de segurança, além do id do usuário. Assim quando o usuário clicar neste link, essa action receberia este token e faria a descriptografia dele para obter estes dados e assim confirmar se é um link válido.

Independente da parte que lhe expliquei sobre a criptografia, encontrei [este tutorial da Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset) que mostra como criar um registro de usuários com **confirmação de e-mail**, ou seja, basicamente é o mesmo princípio que você quer utilizar, inclusive eles utilizam o `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`.

Espero que tenha ajudado. Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição.

Abraço!